# gnuplot reading from data to plot bar chars

Tags: subprocess, gnuplot

I have a file with two columns

```
9 5
10 3
11 0
12 25
13 50
14 80
etc
```

What is the best way to plot bar char using gnuplot? Is using subprocess with gnuplot the best way? Ideally the graph should be in .pdf and in png as I want to put these on a website later on.

I would really appreciate your input/advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example, how to plot a bar chart with `gnuplot` using the plotting style `with boxes`

```
set terminal pngcairo size 1000,800 font ',12'
set output 'output.png'

set xlabel 'xlabel' font ',18'
set ylabel 'ylabel' font ',18'

set boxwidth 0.9 
set style fill solid 0.3

set offset 0.5, 0.5, 10, 0

plot 'data.txt' with boxes linewidth 3 title ''
```

With the data you showed, this gives the following output image:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks. Is there a way of using python in this. I want to set up crontab to run my script which should produce the graphs daily?

At the moment my data file is in .txt so I will need to save it in .dat file I presume?

Comment: @Chino No, I used exactly the same data format as you. I'm just used to use `.dat` as prefix for data files of any kind. You can also `plot 'file.txt'`, or `plot 'my.weird.ext'`. The extension is irrelevant, as long as the content is fine, your data is formatted properly `:)`. You could also call a python script which writes to `sys.stdout` and `plot '< python myprocess.py'`. But I have no experience calling `gnuplot` directly from `python`.

Comment: Thank you for replying back, my .txt is formatted with only single space between the columns. I assumed it has to be .dat as most examples have that ext.

I was hoping how to best do this in python preferably.

Comment: @Chino What exactly do you need python for? Calling gnuplot with the script? Plotting the data on-the-fly without storing? Somthing else?

Comment: Yes, I have some python script which is scheduled to run on crontab daily. So when those files gets processed in the format I have given example above. I can schedule the gnuplot pyhon script the next day to exact yesterdays data and plot the graph as .pdf and .png.